# Ember data - send only properties that have values

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model with many attributes and certain associations. Most of them may or may not be null.
I am trying to do an Ajax call with this model as a payload, and certain properties can be null.

I want to send only the properties that have values, and not null, including associations.

Is it possible? Kindly let me know if it is possible.

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
      name : DS.attr('string'),
      address : DS.hasMany('address')
 });
```

Comment: how are you making the Ajax call?

Comment: I'm just doing model.save() and using jsonapiadapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you should override your serializer. If you use the default `JSONAPISerializer` the right place is the `serializeAttribute` hook:

```
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  serializeAttribute(snapshot, json, key) {
    if(snapshot.attr(key) != null) {
      this._super(...arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

This will work for attributes, not relationships. However this is basically the same.

You can also write your own serializer. Then you just implement the `serialize` hook, and write any code you want to create the JSON you want.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use REST with [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) semantics, your server should support the http [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) method.  When Ember knows that a record already exists on the server, [it will send a PATCH message](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/#toc_persisting-records) with only the attributes that have the `dirty` flag set.  If a record does not exist on the server, then Ember will send a POST instead of PATCH.  You can also override the method used by implementing `methodForRequest` in `JSONAPIAdapter`

You weren't clear in your question if this is a new record rather than an update.

Comment: I'm really sorry about it. It's a new record. I don't have an issue with patch, coz patch works fine. During post, even null values go. Which do you think is better? To handle this in ui or server ? And if UI, how do I do it ?

Comment: methodForRequest is currently disabled. https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2016/11/30/ember-2-10-released.html https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/4686

Comment: Oh okay. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: `methodForRequest` is still in the 2.14 API: https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter/methods/methodForRequest?anchor=methodForRequest  Also, @kumkanillam, there is no mention of `methodForRequest` on the link you provided.

Comment: @SteveH. that method introduced in and the code is wrapped with feature flag `ds-improved-ajax` and it's disabled and removed from beta. but that does not reflect in API doc. please correct me if I am wrong.